# What is the difference between the tree-cut decomposition and tree decomposition?

Tags: tree, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

if i want to find the cut-width and tree-width, and compare them. Therefore, in the following example how the tree-cut decomposition and tree decomposition would look like?

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEEek.png)

as far as i understood from literature, they both correspond to the same decomposition.